# How to use Travis CI build matrix with multiple Ubuntu distributions?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

Here is my `.travis.yml` config file:

```yaml
language: cpp

os:
  - linux
  - osx
dist:
  - xenial
  - bionic
osx_image:
  - xcode10
  - xcode11
  - xcode12
compiler:
  - clang
  - gcc
env:
  - CMAKE_GENERATOR='Unix Makefiles'
  - CMAKE_GENERATOR='Ninja'
  - CMAKE_GENERATOR='Xcode'

jobs:
  exclude:
    - os:
        - linux
      env:
        - CMAKE_GENERATOR='Xcode'
    # On MacOS, 'gcc' and 'g++' are just aliases for 'clang' and 'clang++'.
    - os:
        - osx
      compiler:
        - gcc

script:
  - ./build.sh
```

What I would like, is for my config to build a `2 (dist) x 2 (compiler) x 2 (env)` matrix for Linux, and a `3 (osx_image) x 3 (env)` matrix for MacOS. However, there are no jobs created which use the Ubuntu Bionic distribution. I looked at the reference for the [os](https://config.travis-ci.com/ref/os) and [dist](https://config.travis-ci.com/ref/dist) config variables, and found that `os` can be of type *Enum (String)* or *Sequence of Enum (String)*, whereas `dist` can **only** be of type *Enum (String)*, so it seems that I'm using the `dist` config variable incorrectly, above.

Could someone please explain how I could properly use the build matrix with multiple Ubuntu distributions?